# titlesec entered into horizontal mode during tableofcontents or printindex

Tags: titlesec, tufte, ebook

I am trying to convert a 300 page book originally done with pdflatex and the tufte package into an ebook. For the conversion I have been using LuaLaTex and the tex4ebook package as described [here](https://d800fotos.wordpress.com/2015/01/19/create-e-books-from-latex-tex-files-ebook-aus-latex-tex-dateien-erstellen/)

At this point I have all the minor issues worked out except I am unable to generate either a \tableofcontents or an \printindex (I have tried this separately). In both cases, processing stops early on with the error:

Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode.

I know enough latex to get simple things done and am a relatively infrequent user.  I really have no idea why this error is being thrown or how to resolve. Frustrating as 98% of the conversion is done and fine.  Can somebody give an idea of what might be causing this? (package conflict, something else?)

Comment: Still do not know why this happens or what causes but on fluke I typed 'quit' into console and processing continued.  Had to do that a few more times.  TOC was generated, looks correct as does a quick flip through of the text.  Index was generated but was duplicate of paper book and not hyperlinked.     So still nothing on the original question but at least able to make a degree of progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not knowledgeable enough to say why but the problem appears to be with the titleformat{\chapter} in the tufte-common.def   Note, there is no issue when generating pdf with either pdflatex or lualatex, only when processing with tex4ebook/tex4ht

So commenting out/replacing like so allows processing to continue normally

```
%\titleformat{\chapter}%
%  [display]% shape
%  {\relax\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\begin{fullwidth}}{}}% format applied to label+text
%  {\itshape\huge\thechapter}% label
%  {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
%  {\huge\rmfamily\itshape}% before the title body
%  [\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\end{fullwidth}}{}]% after the title body

\titleformat{\chapter}%
[display]% shape
{\itshape\huge}
{\thechapter}% label
{0em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
{\huge\rmfamily\itshape}% before the title body
[] %
```

Hope that helps if anyone else runs into this issue.